# React query infinite scroll pageParams is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am trying to get data Using useInfiniteQuery, but on my console, I am getting the data but the pageParams is showing undefined, am I missing something to get the pageParams?

[image]

Here is my query hook

```
const useActivityFeedData = () => {
  const {data} = useInfiniteQuery(
    ACTIVITY_FEED,
    ({pageParam}) => Api.user.getActivityFeedData(pageParam),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage: any) => lastPage?.meta,
    },
  );
console.log(data)
};
```

My API

```
  getActivityFeedData: (pageParam: number) => {
    console.log(pageParam, 'pageParam'); // undefined

    return api.get(
      `/rest/s1/eyon/viewer/channel/activity-feed?pageSize=10&pageIndex=0`,
      {},
      {},
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything - this is the intended behaviour. `pageParams` is always calculated for the *next* page, usually from the *previous* result. That's what you do in `getNextPageParams`.

For the first page, there is no "previous result", because it is the first page. That's why the `pageParams` are `undefined`. Note how we use default values during destructuring in the examples, e.g.:

```
const queryResult = useInfiniteQuery(
  ['projects'],
  ({ pageParam = 0 }) => axios.get('/api/projects?cursor=' + pageParam),
  {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.nextCursor,
  }
)
```

for the first page, the `cursor` will be set to `0`, as `pageParam` is `undefined`.

So it's just up to you to convert `undefined` to something that represents "the first page" for your api call.

Comment: Thanks, I was curious about this too, because my pagination works fine but I was seeing the undefined so I wonder if there's anything wrong.